# How to select with the same movement but on a different line

Tags: cursor-movement, search

If I have the folowing file:

```
XX:YY:ZZ foobar: some text
XX:YY:ZZ foobar: some other text
a text breaking the pattern
XX:YY:ZZ foobar: some more text
```

And I want to operate on the differents parts `XX:YY:ZZ foobar:` of the lines. When I am on the first line I can select the text that I want with, for example, `v3f:`. Now when I am on the second or on the last line how can I select this same text without type once again `v3f:`?

*I insist on the fact that I need to select the texts sequentially and not all the occurences at the same time.*

I know the command `gv` which allows to re-select the last selected area but in my case it will select the 16 first characters of the first line which is not what I want.

**To sum it up** How can I execute again the last selection command?

(Also I wasn't sure about the tags I should use for this question don't hesitate to edit/suggest the right ones to use)

Comment: `:help visual-search` simple example for search selected text: `:vmap X y/<C-R>"<CR>" and `gn` - Search forward for the last used search pattern, like with `n`, and start Visual mode to select the match.

Comment: @AlexKroll: I had trouble figuring out what you meant (I think there is a problem in the formatting of your comment) that seems like a nice solution, especially the `gn` part which I didn't know.

Comment: Yes. I've combined two parts and formatting has broken.
First part: search pattern selected in visual mode. You can read about it in vimdoc `:help viusual-search`. it's just simple example.
Second part: navigate forwad to the next matched pattern. Like `n` in normal mode but visual mode have own mapping `gn` for more explanation `:help gn`.

Comment: That's a nice way to do it! I think that it could also be done with doing a first search and then removing the `<C-R>"` part, this way the search will be done on the last search pattern and the user can yank another piece of text without breaking the mapping.  Also if I may suggest you to edit your comment for the comfort of future users that would be nice ;)

Comment: But your question about selection movement. In other word: select from cursor to third colon in other line. My comment covers case for selection exactly same text in other line.

Comment: It's about selecting from cursor to third colon in the same line: `v3f:` will not work if the current line contains less than 3 `:` actually but you're right your comment doesn't covers exactly the same case.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *do* to the `XX:YY:ZZ foobar:` parts? There might be other ways to achieve your goal that don't involve visual mode. (e.g. `:substitute`, `:global`)

Comment: @Rich you're right in this case I finally managed to do what I wanted with a global command. Actually this example wasn't the best to illustrate my purpose, I just remembered I had already faced this case before but couldn't remember precisely the file I was working on. Maybe those other time also I could have done it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a quick mapping:

```
:nnoremap <key> 0v3f:
```

Or use a macro recording:

```
qq
0v3f:
q
```

then:

```
@q
```

Here is another method, lifted from the "experimental" part of my config:

```
function! GetVisualSelection()
  let old_reg = @v
  normal! gv"vy
  let raw_search = @v
  let @v = old_reg
  return substitute(escape(raw_search, '\/.*$^~[]'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
endfunction

nnoremap <key> *``gn<C-g>
inoremap <key> <C-o>gn<C-g>
xnoremap <key> <Esc>:let @/ = GetVisualSelection()<CR>gn<C-g>
```

1. Select your text with `v3f:`.
2. Press `<key>` to enter insert mode.
3. Edit the selection directly.
4. Press `<key>` again to jump to the next match.
5. `GOTO 3`

--- edit ---

`GetVisualSelection()` returns a representation of the selected text suitable for use as a search pattern (escaped slashes and so on).

The normal mode mapping jumps to the next occurrence of the word under the cursor (with `*`), comes back (with ``), selects the last search (with `gn`, here it is the word under the cursor) and switches to select mode (`<C->g`) to allow us to type right away.

The insert mode mapping temporarily jumps out of insert mode (with `<C-o>`) to jump to and select the next occurrence (with `gn`) and switches to select mode.

The visual mode mapping has the same function as the normal mode mapping but it is implemented differently: it goes out of visual mode (with `<Esc>`), places a "prepared" representation of the selected text in the search register (with `:let @/ = GetVisualSelection()<CR>`), jumps to and select the next occurrence (with `gn`) and switches to select mode (with `<C-g>`.

--- endedit ---

Comment: I didn't precise it clearly but I was wondering if there was a built-in solution which would allow not to use macro or mapping, but your 2 first solution works. For the mapping a cool line to add to `vimrc` is `nnoremap <Leader>r :nnoremap <lt>Leader>t ` which allow to quickly redefine the mapping of `<Leader>t`, that could be use to create the quick mapping. For your "experimental solution" I'll have to try it and study it a little bit more because I'm not sure I understand clearly how it works ;)

Comment: Now I understand it better, your last solution is really nice actually! Thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 3):

I think the 'vim way' does not rely on using the visual mode to do something with the selection, but the other way around: do something on the `3f:` - in your case: e.g. `d3f:`. If you do the latter, you can move on the line you want and simply press `.` to repeat that operation.

To answer strictly to your question, you can use:

```
:norm v3f:
```

or

```
:norm ^v3f
```

from the command line, and repeat that on any line you want, with `@:`.

Comment: Indeed you're probably right about the vim way to work... I might be able to find an other way to do what I want. But stricly about my question your solution works for me, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Bonus: after the 1st `@:`, you can use `@@` (which is easier to type), while you don't use the command-line.

Comment: Yep I knew this one but I tend to use it for macros and forgot that it can be used in this case. Great bonus anyway!